# Parse JSON in react.js, json parse

Tags: reactjs, json

I have following JSON. I cant parse this JSON. Please help me.
{
"success":true,
"result":{
"current_page":1,
"data":[
{
"id":8,
"camp_id":null,
"name":"dasfsdef",
"mobile":"4874864646",
"id_proofe_type":null,
"id_proof_no":null,
"status":"Inactive"
},
{
"id":9,
"camp_id":null,
"name":"qwert",
"mobile":"741258963",
"id_proofe_type":null,
"id_proof_no":null,
"status":"Inactive"
},
{
"id":10,
"camp_id":null,
"name":"Ashutosh",
"mobile":"8878590380",
"id_proofe_type":"Driving License",
"id_proof_no":"789456123256",
"status":"Inactive"
}
],
"first_page_url":"http://healthapi.tech-radix.com/api/showusers?page=1",
"from":1,
"last_page":6,
"last_page_url":"http://healthapi.tech-radix.com/api/showusers?page=6",
"links":[
{
"url":null,
"label":"« Previous",
"active":false
},
{
"url":"http://healthapi.tech-radix.com/api/showusers?page=1",
"label":"1",
"active":true
},
{
"url":"http://healthapi.tech-radix.com/api/showusers?page=2",
"label":"2",
"active":false
},
{
"url":"http://healthapi.tech-radix.com/api/showusers?page=3",
"label":"3",
"active":false
},
{
"url":"http://healthapi.tech-radix.com/api/showusers?page=4",
"label":"4",
"active":false
},
{
"url":"http://healthapi.tech-radix.com/api/showusers?page=5",
"label":"5",
"active":false
},
{
"url":"http://healthapi.tech-radix.com/api/showusers?page=6",
"label":"6",
"active":false
},
{
"url":"http://healthapi.tech-radix.com/api/showusers?page=2",
"label":"Next »",
"active":false
}
],
"next_page_url":"http://healthapi.tech-radix.com/api/showusers?page=2",
"path":"http://healthapi.tech-radix.com/api/showusers",
"per_page":3,
"prev_page_url":null,
"to":3,
"total":17
}
}

Answer (score 1):

Depending on where it comes from:

If it is a `Josn` file you can simply import it in the `.js` files in **React project**:

```
import myJson from '[json file address]';
myJosn.result.first_page_url  //----> use it like this for example
```

If it is the response of an API or something like that (in the form of a `Json`), you can also get that response and use it like `myJson` on the above.

And if it is a stringified `Json` you can do this :

```
const myJson = JSON.parse(your_Stringified_Json);
myJosn.result.first_page_url  //----> use it like this for example
```

Comment: this is a api response which i want to parse.

Comment: Please clarify the question you've asked by explaining more about the API response.

Comment: You've just posted a json, and it is not clear, where does it come from? and which one of _axios_, _fetch_ or _XMLHttpRequest_ are you using for getting **this response** from server? explain more about the code block that caused problem to you!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to import it like

```
import * as data from './example.json';
console.log(data);
```